# vim: why block mode selection becomes normal moving-mouse selection

Tags: vim

Observed:

First, 'ctrl+v'+selection always worked before for me. But this time, i got normal moving-mouse selection, instead of column selection. As in:

[image]

Why?

Reason of problem: as suggested by the comment from **Peter van der Heijden** , maybe I missed typed 'v' as 'ctrl-v'.
Sorry that i can not accept your comment as the solution, because i can not do that for a comment.

Comment: well instead of writing a catchy headline - please provide useful information - `version of vim` entries in `.vimrc` concerning select and block select and mouse select; and explaining what 'use normal selection in block mode' means - mouse selection/select with motions.

Comment: Is it possible you pressed `v` instead of `CTRL+V`?

Comment: if I used the mouse to select (in gvim), it would work for me as follows: start selection with mouse, then press `<C-v>` and select in block mode.

Comment: If ever there was an example of how NOT to write an SO question, this is it. Could you please at least remove the profanities.

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have pressed `v` instead of `CTRL+V`. I.e. You released the `CTRL` button before pressing `v`.